# How to keep an absolutely positioned element directly over the position of inline one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow up question to [How can I stop an IFrame reloading when I change it's position in the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233097/how-can-i-stop-an-iframe-reloading-when-i-change-its-position-in-the-dom) if you want the background.

I have an inline div `<div id="leaderboard-slot"></div>` (with a fixed width and height) and another div ("leaderboard-loader") further down the page with the actual content for that div.

For various reasons (see previous thread), I am unable to simply do an appendChild or similar.

Instead, I'm hoping to position leaderboard-loader such that it takes up the space "reserved" by leaderboard slot. I've used some jQuery methods to do this:

```
var loader = $('leaderboard-loader');
var dest = $('leaderboard-slot');
var pos = dest.getPosition();
loader.setStyle('top', pos.y + 'px');
loader.setStyle('left', pos.x + 'px');
```

which I fire on document load and resize. However, if other elements within the page cause a reflow, then the target div moves, but the loader doesn't.

Is there a safe way of doing this - it needs to work when I know nothing else about the page (ie I can't just make this call on any other methods that might cause a reflow, because I don't know what those are).

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting to regret [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233097/how-can-i-stop-an-iframe-reloading-when-i-change-its-position-in-the-dom) now.  Hopefully you can find something better than the absolute positioning workaround.  But, in the spirit of kludgey solutions, you could call the repositioning script on a timer.  *sigh*.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, there is no need for Javascript. Just put `leaderboard-loader` in front of the `leaderboard-slot` tag, give it `position: absolute` and identical width and height. If slot is a normal element, loader will float above it and cover it perfectly.

```
<div id="leaderboard-loader"></div><div id="leaderboard-slot"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Pekka. unfortunately the leaderboard-loader has to appear at the bottom of the document (it loads in a bunch of external scripts that use document.write) - the idea is to allow the whole page to load first before leaderboard-loader.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them **both** in the same relative positioned, 0 margin div, with the temporary div z-indexed on top of the slow loader.

Make them both absoluely positioned in the parent, not the window, at 0:0 and the same size.

You can use opacity  and fade one in as you fade the other one out, or just swap visibility:hidden and visible for the two elements when you are ready..

Comment: see my comment to Pekka - unfortunately they can't be in the same div - need the page to be able to load without the "loader" div first. thanks for the suggestion though :)